# While loop inside a while loop in two different functions?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have two mysql_queries who have two while loops in fetch_assoc. One written inside another. I want to take one while loop inside a function  and another inside another function. How to do that? Help. Here's an example of what I'm trying to say.

```
$query1 = mysql_query('...');
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
$id = $row1['id'];

$query2 = mysql_query('...');
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){ 
$picture = $row2['picture'];

echo $id.'&nbsp;'.$picture;
```

}
   }

I want to take these two inside two different functions..

```
function query1(){
1st query with 1st while loop
}

function query2(){

2nd query with 2nd while loop
}
```

So that I can execute them just the way it is supposed to be..

```
query1();
query2();

echo $id.'&nbsp;'.$picture;
```

How to achieve this? Help.

Comment: If one is inside the other you can't. You could have `query1();` which looks sth like this `while (...) { query2(); }` however

Comment: You can call query2() inside query1()

Comment: like this? query1(query1()); ?

Comment: Inside the body of the query1(), within the while loop. SO you need to only call query1() from the outside.

Comment: For performance, avoid queries in loop, prefer to use 2 queries and use IN() to select values from the other table. (You will have 2 loops but with only 2 queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure it as follows:

```
function query2(){
    //do inner stuff
}
function query1(){
    //do stuff
    query2();
}
query1();
```

Let me know if you need more context!

Comment: thanks. Your code opened many paths.. I'm trying different things now.